# What is the limit of $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{(x-2) \left(x^2+2 x-8\right)}}{x^2-4}$ when $x\to 0$?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I tried to find out the value of limit but when I took $x_-\rightarrow0$ then a result is obtained again when I took $x_+\rightarrow0$ another result was obtained. Can anyone please explain why is this happening?

Is there anything wrong with the question or I was doing it wrong?

I am quite weak at determining limits

Edit: The problem stated above has been solved. The question was wrong instead of $x \to 0$ it should be $x \to 2$ (this will satisfy the question).

Comment: @MohammadSakibShahriar The limit at $x\to 0$ is $-1$ in both directions. The limit at $x\to 2$ are different

Comment: When the function at that value is not of any indeterminate form.... Just put the value in the function and that will be your answer. Incase of $x\to\ 0$ , the function approaches $-1$ ... Also if you want to calculate at $x\to\ 2$, try cancelling the common factors from numerator and denominator and then try to evaluate at that value.

Comment: @MohammadSakibShahriar I posted a solution if you need it.
Make sure to check the quick tutorial form the MathJax formatting used in this site, Here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you meant to evaluate the limit as $x \to 2$.

Factorize, and ***remember*** that $\sqrt {y^2}$ is not just $y$; it is $|y|$. This is crucial.

What's the behavior of the function $\frac {|y|}{y}$ near zero?

---

Solution:

> $$ \frac {\sqrt{(x-2)(x^2 +2x -8)}}{x^2 -4}=\frac {\sqrt{(x-2)(x+4)(x-2)}}{(x-2)(x+2)}= \frac {\sqrt {(x-2)^2} \sqrt {x+4} }{(x-2)(x+2)} = \frac {|x-2|}{x-2}  \frac {\sqrt {x+4}}{x+2} $$
>  Now as $x \to 2$ the function $\frac {\sqrt {x+4}}{x+2} \to \frac {\sqrt {6}}{4}$, however the other half $\frac {|x-2|}{x-2}$ (aka $sign(x-2)$) is equal to $1$ as we approach $2$ from the right, and is equal to $-1$ as we approach $2$ from the left. Therefore the solution will be $-\frac {\sqrt {6}}{4}$ as $x \to 2^{\mathbf -}$ and $\frac {\sqrt {6}}{4}$ as $x \to 2^{\mathbf +}$.

Comment: Someone new to calculus may mistake your "!" Sign as the **factorial** sign.......please remove them.

Comment: True. I just removed the exclamation points.

Comment: Thank you sir.  The question was regarding x→0 and told to prove that the limit doea not exist.I guess the question is wrong

Comment: I tried to solvw the math in the way the question wanted so i replaced x+ with 1-h such that h→1 and obtained the limit L=-√3 again i replaced x- with h-1 such that h→1 and obtained L=-√(5/3)

Comment: The question is wrong, the function is continuous near 0 therefore $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0) = -1$. Surely it's a typo and they meant to say that you should prove that the limit as $x \to 2$ does not exist. Can you do that?

Comment: @MohammadSakibShahriar trust me, you must prove that the limit does not exist near 2 ;- )

Comment: Yes sir now I can prove that the function does not have a limit when x→2.

Comment: @MohammadSakibShahriar Show your work, or you can answer your own question... make sure to edit your initial post to specify that the book has a typo and that it should be $x \to 2$ and not $x \to 0$.